# Combine words with nearest index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file of terms with their index in context in two languages, as  this format

```
1. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights)>> (3- droits de l'homme, 7- droit des travailleurs)
2. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights, 19- women rights)>> (5- droits de l'homme, 15- les droits des femmes)
```

The goal is to attach every word in the first language(English) to the closest word in the sentence in the other language (French), so the output will be

```
 human rights : droits de l'homme
 workers rights : droit des travailleurs
 human rights : droits de l'homme
 women rights  : les droits des femmes
```

this is the comment:human rights> droits de l'homme: since the n.2(position of "human rights" in English sentence) is close to n.3 (position of "droits de l'homme" in French sentence), compared to the other numbers present in the French list (in this case n.7); and in the same way "workers rights">"droit des travailleurs"

human rights> droits de l'homme: since the n.2(position of "human rights" in English sentence) is close to n.5 (position of "droits de l'homme" in French sentence), compared to the other numbers present in the French list (in this case n.15); and in the same way "women rights"> "les droits des femmes": since the n.19 is close to n.15 (compared to the n.10)

Can someone find same way to get this output?

Comment: Could you expose what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please format your code snippets in the last 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not complete but should will get you started:

```
from bisect import bisect
import re

with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("(\d+)")
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.lstrip("0123456789. ").split(">> ")
        a_keys = [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(a)]
        b_keys =  [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(b)]
        a = a.strip("()\n").split(",")
        b = b.strip("()\n").split(",")
        for ele, s in zip(a, a_keys):
            ind = bisect(b_keys, s, hi=len(b) - 1)
            print("{} -> {}".format(ele, b[ind]))
```

Output:

```
2- human rights -> 3- droits de l'homme
 10- workers rights ->  7- droit des travailleurs
2- human rights -> 5- droits de l'homme
 10- workers rights ->  15- les droits des femmes
 19- women rights ->  15- les droits des femmes
```

You need to fix the formatting and do one more check to find the min based  on the absolute difference of the ele at ind and ind -1.

To catch where the absolute differece of the previous ind-1 element is less:

```
from bisect import bisect
import re

with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("(\d+)")
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.lstrip("0123456789. ").split(">> ")
        a_keys = [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(a)]
        b_keys = [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(b)]
        a = a.strip("()\n").split(",")
        b = b.strip("()\n").split(",")
        for ele, k in zip(a, a_keys):
            ind = bisect(b_keys, k, hi=len(b) - 1)
            ind -= k - b_keys[ind] < b_keys[ind-1] - k
            print("{} -> {}".format(ele, b[ind]))
```

So for:

```
1. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights)>> (3- droits de l'homme, 7- droit des travailleurs)
2. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights, 19- women rights)>> (1- droits de l'homme ,4- foobar, 15- les droits des femmes)
```

We get:

```
2- human rights -> 3- droits de l'homme
 10- workers rights ->  7- droit des travailleurs
2- human rights -> 1- droits de l'homme 
 10- workers rights ->  15- les droits des femmes
 19- women rights ->  15- les droits des femmes
```

The original code would output `2- human rights -> 4- foobar` as we did not consider where the absolute difference of previous element is less.

Using the data in your comment shows the difference:

```
l1 = [10, 33, 50, 67]
l2 = [7, 16, 29, 55]

for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
```

Output:

```
10 -> 16
33 -> 55
50 -> 55
67 -> 55
```

Now with checking the previous element:

```
l1 = [10, 33, 50, 67]
l2 = [7, 16, 29, 55]

for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    ind -= s - l2[ind-1] < l2[ind] - s
    print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
```

Output:

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 55
67 -> 55
```

[bisect.bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect)

> Similar to bisect_left(), but returns an insertion point which comes after (to the right of) any existing entries of x in a.
>   The returned insertion point i partitions the array a into two halves so that all(val <= x for val in a[lo:i]) for the left side and all(val > x for val in a[i:hi]) for the right side.

So bisecting gets where the element should land in your ordered list of numbers with all elements less than positioned to the left of the element so that means the element is greater than all previous. To find the closest based on the difference we need to check the previous element as the abs difference may be less.

Comment: forget you were using python3

Comment: There are some edge cases to catch. Duty calls now but I will edit when I get back on my comp later and explain.

Comment: @user3573552,  *You need to fix the formatting* **and do one more check to find the min based on the absolute difference of the ele at ind and ind -1.**

Comment: @user3573552, do you understand the difference now and why we need to check the previous element?

Comment: Then it would add complexity, you would need to remove elements from the list i.e `l2[ind]`

Comment: what happens if that is the case, there is no match?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787554/using-bisect-for-combing-items-with-a-distance-condition/32787852?noredirect=1#comment53415282_32787852