# Using bisect for combing items with a distance condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following two lists

```
 l1 = [10, 33, 50, 67]
 l2 = [7, 16, 29, 65]
```

I use `bisect` to combine the closest numbers in the two lists. I use this code

```
for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    ind -= abs(l2[ind-1] - s) < l2[ind] - s
    print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
```

This code gives the output:

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 65
67 -> 65
```

In order to get rid of the duplication of items in the second list, I used this after the print:

```
    if ind == len(l2) - 1: break
```

But in the case of if statement the output is:

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 65
```

What I want here is that the combination will be done with the condition that the distance between the closest numbers are not greater than 6, but without breaking the loop for items that fail this test, as in the case of my last code. I want this output:

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> -- # here for the condition
67 -> 65
```

Comment: So you want to map from a number in list one to the closest number in list two, provided that the number in list two is no further than 6 away from the number in list one?

Comment: yes, this is what I want

Comment: Let me know if the below answer is off base for some reason!

Comment: what should `50 -> ` output?

Comment: here 50 -> null, becuase 50  does not have an item to be combined with

Answer (score 2):

because we have bisected we know which elements are greater so we can just test after subtracting:

```
from bisect import bisect
for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    ind -= s - l2[ind-1] < l2[ind] - s
    tmp = l2[ind]
    print("{} -> {}".format(s,tmp if tmp  - s < 6 else "NULL"))
```

using the code from your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780128/2141635):

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    r = re.compile("(\d+)")
    for line in f:
        a, b = line.lstrip("0123456789. ").split(">> ")
        a_keys = [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(a)]
        b_keys = [int(i.group()) for i in r.finditer(b)]
        a = a.strip("()\n").split(",")
        b = b.strip("()\n").split(",")
        for ele, k in zip(a, a_keys):
            ind = bisect(b_keys, k, hi=len(b) - 1)
            ind -= k - b_keys[ind] < b_keys[ind-1] - k
            print("{} -> {}".format(ele, b[ind] if abs(b_keys[ind] - k) < 5 else "NULL"))
```

Input:

```
1. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights)>> (3- droits de l'homme, 7- droit des travailleurs)
2. (2- human rights, 10- workers rights, 19- women rights)>> (1- droits de l'homme ,4- foobar, 15- les droits des femmes)
```

Output:

```
2- human rights -> 3- droits de l'homme
 10- workers rights ->  7- droit des travailleurs
2- human rights -> 1- droits de l'homme 
 10- workers rights -> NULL
 19- women rights ->  15- les droits des femmes
```

If `b_keys[ind]` which is the closest value + `n` is less than `k` we have a match, else we output null.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a matter of checking what you want the second value of your tuple to be. I've reformulated what you're doing a bit for clarity (by separating out the printing concern from the calculating a tuple concern):

```
l1 = [10, 33, 50, 67]
l2 = [7, 16, 29, 65]

def bmap(s, lst):
    ind = bisect(lst, s, hi=len(lst) - 1)
    ind -= abs(lst[ind-1] - s) < lst[ind] - s
    # check that the result will be in bounds and return something appropriate
    return (s, lst[ind]) if abs(lst[ind] - s) < 6 else (s, "--")

result = [bmap(s, l2) for s in l1]
for (a, b) in result:
    print("{} -> {}".format(a,b))
```

Note that the `6` is an arbitrary value and should probably be replaced by a constant or named variable so someone reading the code can better understand what is going on.

Basically what I've done here is set up a function to do the mapping from a single arbitrary value to a member of an arbitrary list. Then we run that function across each value in your first list with your second list as the list input. Finally, we print the result, rather than trying to do it as part of the mapping function.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Does it have a line number associated? I'm not entirely sure I understand "because I apply the code for a list of str"?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I'm clear on what your input is. Your original question is asking about a list of integers, but you're clearly running this on some other input. Can you provide the actual input you're running this on?

Comment: (Padraic got to it before me, so I trust this aspect is answered!)